# Expect in Bash Script Spawn Id exp4 not open Error

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I get an error
`send: Spawn id exp4 not open   while executing`
and I don't understand enough about Expect to know why this is happening

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect_ssh() {
        local ub_serv_ip="192.168.233.132"
        local ssh_username="administrator"
        local ssh_password="Password123!"
        local ub_serv_ip="127.0.0.1"
        local ssh_username="nkloney"

local script=$(expect <<EOF
        spawn ssh $ssh_username@$ub_serv_ip
        expect "*assword:"
        send "$password\r"
        expect "$ "
        send "hostname\r"
        expect "$ "
        set hostname \$expect_out(buffer)
        set hostname [string trim \$hostname]
        send "hostname -i\r"
        expect "$ "
        set ip_address \$expect_out(buffer)
        set ip_address [string trim \$ip_address]
        send "exit\r"
        expect eof
        puts \$hostname
        puts \$ip_address
EOF
)
        local hostname=$(echo "$script" | sed -n '1p')
        local ip_address=$(echo "$script" | sed -n '2p')
        export SERVER_HOSTNAME="$hostname"
        export SERVER_IP_ADDRESS="$ip_address"
}

expect_ssh

echo "Server Hostname: $SERVER_HOSTNAME"
echo "Server IP Address: $SERVER_IP_ADDRESS"
```

I want it to output the variables so I can use them in a Bash script, but instead, the program takes like a full minute to run, and then it outputs the error.

Comment: Using string concatenation to substitute variables into code is generally a Bad Idea. Much better form to use a _quoted_ heredoc and have your expect/TCL code refer to the environment for passed-in values; otherwise you get security problems, not just value-specific syntax errors.

Comment: Anyhow, there's no good reason to use expect here at all; you don't need it in the first place. Either do the Right Thing and use key-based authentication, or do the Wrong Thing better by leveraging sshpass instead of trying to use expect to roll your own alternative to it.

Comment: All true above. Assuming you are on a exploration, note the `[expect]` is a tag here on S.O. but if you search just `[expect]` it returns no results. When I searched for `[bash] expect script` there are some useful messages, but with many false positives. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209669/exiting-bash-script-for-loop-on-expect-script-expect-error can help. Else you'll have to keep looking. Good show on posting a revised question from an hour ago and Good Luck!

Comment: you can try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) if you are more familiar with bash/shell than expect/tcl.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy unfortunately I have to use Except because the script is for a school assignment, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: "Spawn id not open" usually means the spawned process has exited, but then you send it something. While you're developing your script, use `expect -d` to enable verbose debugging. You'll be able to see if your patterns are matching.

Comment: Interesting. When I read this code, I would expect it to hang indefinitely. You are expanding password, a variable that does not exist, instead of ssh_password. So on the first instance, only "\r" should be sent, leading ssh to prompt you to retry, with likely no "$ " in the answer. Unless the server is configured without retries, ssh exits with authentication failure and your next send tries to send to the already exited ssh process, which leads to the spawn ID error you are getting.